# If $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a piecewise smooth path and if $\beta:[c,d]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a path that can be obtained from

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, change-of-variable, piecewise-continuity

**If $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a piecewise smooth path and if $\beta:[c,d]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a path that can be obtained from $\gamma$ by making a piecewise smooth change  of parameter, then $\beta$ is also piecewise smooth.**

We know that $\beta=\gamma h$ where $h$ is a piecewise smooth path and so we need $\beta(t)=\gamma(h(t))$ to make sense and for this we could not take the same partition that gives me the fact that $h$ is piecewise smooth and this would serve me to prove that $\beta$ is piecewise smooth path? Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it just me? Or isn't the actual question rather unclear?

Comment: @skyking why? what do not you understand?

Comment: What you're asking exactly.

Comment: @skyking that $\beta$ is piecewise smooth path

Comment: I got the impression that you proved that, but yes $\beta$ would be piecewise smooth - it follows from the fact that a composition of piecewise smooth functions is itself piecewise smooth.

Comment: @skyking ok! And how do I show that a composition of piecewise smooth function is itself smooth?